# wpa_supplicant: How to connect to a particular ESSID from a script?

Tags: linux

```
network={
       ssid="ana"
       bssid=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
       key_mgmt=NONE
       auth_alg=OPEN
       wep_key0=xxxxxxxxxxxxx
       #identity 0 ana
       disabled=1
}
```

How do I modify this to support connecting via a script by manually doing:

```
dial ana` or `dial gremlin
```

Right now, when I start `wpa_supplicant`, it autoconnects based on *priority* or *disabled* and I'd like to turn that behavior off and manually specify the ESSID I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
wpa_cli select_network $(wpa_cli list_networks | grep gremlin | cut -f 1)
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not aware of being able to use dial but you can select which network to connect to using wpa_cli

list networks:

```
/sbin/wpa_cli list_networks
```

select a different one:

```
/sbin/wpa_cli select_network <n>
```

where <n> is the number of the network

Comment: 'dial' is a script i wrote. if i had to do 'dial ana', i'd have to parse wpa_supplicant to extract the number of the network because I don't know of a way to do a direct wpa_cli select_network "ana"

Comment: I see, sorry, I didn't grasp that from  your original description.